# Buck regulator's feedback voltage far lower than expected

Tags: buck, feedback

UPDATE: Just found some weird behavior. When measuring V<sub>FB</sub> on the resistor pads with a voltmeter, I shorted V<sub>FB</sub> to ENABLE (4.36V) with the voltmeter probe. This caused the buck to start correctly outputting 12.36V. Connecting the voltmeter probes to GND and V<sub>FB</sub> again caused V<sub>OUT</sub> to go back down to tens of mV. This behavior consistently repeats when I do this.

Datasheets: Buck regulator: [AOZ2261NQI-12](https://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOZ2261NQI-12.pdf) Inductor: [PQ2614BLA-150K](https://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/PQ2614.pdf)

I am using the buck regulator to convert 24V down to 12V. However, I am seeing weird behavior where V<sub>FB</sub> is much lower than expected. The datasheet states it should be 0.6V +/- 6mV, but I measure ~18.5mV on mine. The voltage divider circuit is functioning correctly, I measure V<sub>OUT</sub> as 390mV which is the correct magnification of the feedback voltage. Below are my schematic and board layout. This is my first time designing a buck regulator circuit so I do not really know where to begin debugging this. Any insights for which voltage/current levels to monitor or R/C values to mess with would be greatly appreciated!

I do notice that the maximum feedback input bias current is given as 200nA on page 5 of the data sheet. Of course the rest of that current would be travelling through the 10kOhm resistor to GND, but how exactly does the feedback input bias current play into that? Could that be limiting my V<sub>OUT</sub> level?

More info:

V<sub>IN</sub> measures at 23.54V. V<sub>VCC</sub> measures at 4.99V. V<sub>EN</sub> measures at 4.15V. AGND and PGND have a 0.0V offset voltage. C<sub>OUT</sub> is actually 47uF, not 88uF. I realized after I ordered the PCBs that it needed to be closer to 22uF but couldn't find any in the right package. 47uF should still be fine.

The first time I powered on my circuit, V<sub>FB</sub> measured at 4.5mV. I applied a little more solder paste around the edges of the IC and reflowed again. Now V<sub>FB</sub> is 18.5mV. So possibly it is a soldering problem? The IC comes in a QFN-23L package, so the leads are pretty inaccessible with the tools I have. I have verified that none of the pins are shorted with each other, but it is possible one or multiple have an insufficient connection to the pad. My next step is to solder up a second circuit on another PCB and see if I get similar behavior.

I can post my calculations for frequency, inductor ripple, etc. if that would be helpful.

[image: PCB layout]

[image: Schematic]

Here are some waveform captures:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO5jZ.jpg]

steady-state waveforms

[image]

waveforms at power-on

Comment: What do the waveforms look like?

Comment: FYI, the edit to add waveform images failed to do so.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy thanks, classic haha. I'm working on it.

Comment: @TimWilliams are there other values I can grab data of that would be useful?

Comment: Seems to be working now.

Comment: FYI, this appears to be a side-wettable QFN part. You can inspect the soldering by looking for toe fillets around the base of the part. You may want a loupe, microscope or other magnification to get a good look at it. Seeing the glint of the fillets as you nudge the part during reflow also helps see how the part's pads are aligned on the footprint.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks, I have been checking the sides and from what I can tell it looks soldered, but it's more that I cant use a voltmeter to verify the connections that gives me uncertainty. Separate from the soldering, was there anything that stood out to you from the waveforms I posted?

Comment: As far as measurements, all of them would be good. It looks like it's shorted, or not starting up, so something with the startup or fault circuitry would be of interest.

Comment: @TimWilliams okay, I'll look into what the startup behavior (or lack thereof) might be telling me. I added a quick update at the top with a weird situation that is causing the chip to start working, which supports that something is blocking startup.

Comment: Re: your last update, maybe 1M is too much for the pull up resistor on EN. Also have look at page 9 of the datasheet regarding Vfb tracking Vss. What does PGOOD look like during/after power on?

Comment: @DamienD Yeah I had that thought and checked the EN resistor. Using 10k instead, I saw no change except that shorting it with FB no longer caused a good output. Vss is low, around 0.03V when the chip is in a bad state, and at 4.99V when its in a good state.   I'll track PGOOD, but I think I checked during an earlier trial and it was high.

Comment: @InBedded16 and what if you briefly toggle EN to GND instead after power up? Could be a power sequencing issue.

Comment: @DamienD sorry, blew a chip and had to remake the circuit. Toggling EN to GND does in fact fix the issue - the moment I release EN, Vout goes up to 12.36V. If you want to make an answer explaining this solution I will happily accept it! And to add on, on pg4 the datasheet does in fact say to assert EN high after IN and VCC are "well supplied." EN comes straight from the VCC supply so there must not be enough of a delay through the pullup resistor.

Comment: Sheesh, they really don't rate this thing very well, do they: no leakage current specified for EN pin at all. I suppose they expect it to be driven by a CMOS logic output (>= 1.8V), but without a current spec, who even knows if that's a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

> So possibly it is a soldering problem?

If you aren't getting output, check the startup. Look at Vin Vout and the switching gate if it's not internal.

If you are worried about solder on many QFN's they will have a very small piece of metal on the top OR you can hit the top of the exposed pad and see if you are actually making a connection. You'll need probes with needle tips to do that and a DMM with continuity mode.

But really it would be good to have a sim or eval board of the buck and be able to compare the voltages and startup sequence. Make sure the components are the same between them. If you changed anything from the reference design I would make your design like the reference design and then change component values.

Comment: Interesting,. might look into ordering some of those as we move into more QFN packages. Updated my question with this info, but just found some pretty weird behavior when shorting Vfb to Ven. I'll look into what the startup behavior is telling me as well, thank you.

Comment: Your edit is a really solid idea too - I had poked around for sample circuits but hadn't thought to actually grab an off the shelf eval board for testing. Definitely adding that to the circuit prototyping procedure from now on.

Comment: It's easier to have a dev board or something that you know works when DC/DC's don't work. There are a lot of moving pieces and you need to cross the things that are working off the list.